# post and receiving data using jQuery asp.net mvc 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have looked through multiple posts trying to explain this, but most of them are just basic examples posting text and so on. I now that there is possible to use Ajax.BeginForm or jQuery to post. I'm not a very skilled JavaScript dev. But maybe someone have some thought of what to use. Ok, to the code.

I have created a ViewModel which holds the data I need

```
 public class AvviksModel
{
    public Avvik Avvik { get; set; }
    public List<AvviksNotat> Notater { get; set; }
    public DateTime AvvikRegistrertTid { get; set; }
    //public List<AnsattModel> Ansatte { get; set; }
    public String NewNote { get; set; }
    public int RegistrertAvAnsNummer { get; set; }        
}
```

Here comes my details View:

```
@model EL4.Administrasjon.Models.AvviksModel
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/Form.css" />
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>@Model.Avvik.Subject</h2>

<div id="contact-area">

  <label for="TidRegistrert">Tid registrert</label>
<input type="text" name="TidRegistrert" id="TidRegistrert" value="@Model.Avvik.RegistrertTid" readonly="true" />

<label for="ansnr">Avviks ID</label>
<input type="text" name="AvviksID" id="AvviksID" value="@Model.Avvik.AvviksID" readonly="true" />

<label for="ansnr">Kategori</label>
<input type="text" name="cat" id="cat" value="@Model.Avvik.AvviksKategori.Navn" readonly="true" />

<label for="GjelderAns">Gjelder ansatt</label>
<input type="text" name="gjelderAns" id="gjelderAns" value="@Model.Avvik.GjelderAnsattNr" readonly="true" />

<label for="RegistrertAvAns">Registrert av</label>
<input type="text" name="RegistrertAvAns" id="RegistrertAvAns" value="@Model.Avvik.RegistrertAvIDAnsNr" readonly="true" />                
</div>    
@foreach (var item in Model.Avvik.AvviksNotat) {
<div class="gradientBoxesWithOuterShadows">
    <h3>@item.SkrevetAv</h3>    
    @item.SkrevetDato<br />
        
        <p>@item.Note</p>
    </div>       
}
```

Here is my controller

```
     public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id != null)
        {
            AvviksModel model = new AvviksModel();
            HM_000_EL4Entities entHm = new HM_000_EL4Entities();

            Avvik TheAvvik = ent.Avvik.Where(a => a.AvviksID == id).FirstOrDefault();

            if (TheAvvik != null)
            {                    
                model.Avvik = TheAvvik;
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        
        return View();
```

So the thing I would like to do, is the list of "AvviksNotat" at the bottom. I would like to create a text box at the bottom of the details form, which I can enter a new comment, post this to the server, and return the new result at the top of the list of "AvviksNotat". Would also be cool using an animation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on this, kind of.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddNotat", "Avvik", new AjaxOptions
{
 HttpMethod = "GET",
 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
 UpdateTargetId = "notes",
 OnSuccess ="AfterInsert"
}))
{
 <h3>Legg til kommentar</h3>
 <label for="note">Notat</label>     
 <textarea name="notatText" id="notatText" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>

 <label for="ans">Registert av</label>
 <input type="text"  name="ans" value="@Model.Avvik.RegistrertAvIDAnsNr" />
 <input type="submit" value="Legg til" id="TheAddNoteButton"/>
 @Html.Hidden("id",Model.Avvik.AvviksID)
 }
```

Comment: Maybe there is a better way to do this. One of the problems I see here is the hidden in the bottom, this id is available in the Model, but I'm not sure how to pass this to the controller with the Ajax call without adding it to the form like I do here.